# Remove and Add class on load based on element id in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I select two buttons the page reloads and there are two values that are assigned to variables.  I am trying to set it up so when the page loads it removes a class and adds one based on what the value of the two variables is.

I get the variables by pulling the value that is passed from two hidden input fields and their id's

```
<input id="noType" name="noType" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input id="noAssign" name="noAssign" type="hidden" value="0" />
```

I grab their values on load.  Then I have buttons with ids `type1 type2 type3` that I add and remove the classes from.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var type = document.getElementById("noType").value;
    var assign = document.getElementById("noAssign").value;
    $("type" + type).removeClass("btn-xxx")
           .addClass("btn-success");
    $("assigned" + assign).removeClass("btn-xxx")
           .addClass("btn-success");

});
```

I am almost 100% sure I'm grabbing the correct ids off of the `getElementById` from the hidden inputs and attaching using them properly when trying to reference the id of the buttons.  The classes are not being added or removed.  What am I missing?

These are the buttons

```
<button id="type1" class="btn-t btn-xxx type-button" 
onclick="SetType(1);"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-fw">
</i>Invitation</button><button id="type2" class="btn-t btn-xxx type-button" 
onclick="SetType(2);"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-fw">
</i>Assistance</button><button id="type3" class="btn-t btn-xxx type-button" 
onclick="SetType(3);">
<i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-fw">
</i>Finalize</button>
```

Comment: You need to select the elements with jQuery way `$('id-of-element')` to work with `removeClass()` and any others functions that jQuery provide.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com and http://try.jquery.com are great introductions to using jQuery.

Comment: Use the jQuery selector method like @Imgonzalves mentions, or use `classList.remove( );` ..  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: @TheDizzle You may want to consider posting a new question rather than editing this question. Your original question has already been answered and accepted and to change it now may be cause confusion. Just a suggestion. If you do post a new question, consider rolling back your edit to restore your original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `removeClass()` and `addClass()` are jQuery functions.

The error is correct as `document.getElementById("type" + type)` returns DOM element and they don't have above methods. Same operations can be performed using [ID Selector (“#id”)](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

> Selects a single element with the given id attribute.

*Use*

```
$("#type" + type).removeClass("btn-xxx").addClass("btn-success");
$("#assigned" + assign).removeClass("btn-xxx").addClass("btn-success");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help with this.  I didn't even notice my not using `#` to reference the ids.  Perfect answer!